# Flask-Application crashes when print is used in "before_request" (IOError)

Tags: python, flask

Good evening!

In my tiny flask-demo-application, I've encountered a pretty weird (at least for me) problem.
If I start the application, do some database-stuff etc. everything works fine. But as soon as I restart the application (using PyCharm 3.0 if that matters), I get IOError (OError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument) when I try to .

I've identified the source of that: and it's the print statement!

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = sqlite3.connect(app.config["DATABASE"])
    print "debug: connecting to db" #<--- this causes the application to crash
```

If I delete that line, everything works like it should. It's probably a stupid question, but I have no idea why this happens and it's really, really bugging me :-/

EDIT: Additional Information:
Python: ActivePython 2.7, OS: Win 8.1

Other related code:

Config Module:

```
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = "testkey"
DATABASE = "dbdb.db"
```

Main module:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config")

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    #print "something" <-- would cause IOError
    g.db = sqlite3.connect(app.config["DATABASE"])

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    #print "something" <-- would also cause IOError
    db = getattr(g, "db", None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def admin():
    if request.method == "GET":
        userlist = g.db.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
        booklist = g.db.execute("SELECT * FROM books").fetchall()
        return render_template("main.html", userlist = userlist, booklist = booklist)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

So there is only one view. As mentioned, the crash appears ONLY when I restart the application (first time running always goes smooth) and try to access the view. After a (random?!) amount of time it goes back to normal. My guess would be that some DB-connection or something like that is not getting closed when I restart.

EDIT2:
Whats happening if I leave BOTH print-statements (see above) in the code:
There is no error message in the console, only the Browser shows me (thanks to the debugger) some information. Interestingly, with both print-statements in my code the error-message alternates between those two:

First:

IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app

response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.preprocess_request()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1666, in preprocess_request

 [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] rv = func()

File "C:\Users\MrTrustworthy\PycharmProjects\DB_Flasktest\DB_Flasktest.py", line 31, in before_request

print "print from before_request"
```

SECOND:

IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in wsgi_app

ctx.push()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 303, in push

top.pop(top._preserved_exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 341, in pop

self.app.do_teardown_request(exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1714, in do_teardown_request

rv = func(exc)

File "C:\Users\MrTrustworthy\PycharmProjects\DB_Flasktest\DB_Flasktest.py", line 38, in teardown_request

print "print from teardown_request"
```

Cheers,
MT

Comment: Knew it was windows! I saw many problems like this with windows platforms, i can confirm that this is working with no problems on OS X and Linux platform. I am using PyCharm 3 with Python 2.7, yes probably some resource is still open or something do not really know.

Comment: Damn it, so no print's for me then i guess... thanks for testing it though :D

Comment: Yeah no problem, maybe someone will now more. In the meantime you can try logging to standart output with logging module.